# django using specific instance for ModelForm object

Tags: django, forms

For `GET` form_page.html,
my view has a specific my_id to instantiate a form.
(ie, when a user first sees this form_page, an instance is already created for him,
and he's actually modifying it for the first time)

```
form = MyForm(instance=MyClass.objects.get(pk=my_id))
```

For `POST` form_page.html,
I'd like to update the same instance using the same my_id.

I guess I could have a separate hidden field for this my_id and get it when user POST the form.
But this seems not as easy as I expected.

How/where should I embed this my_id so that I can use it to update the same instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually I keep the id in the url

```
url(r'^(?P<id>[\d]+)/edit/$', "edit"),


def edit(request, id=None, **kwargs):
    if id:
        instance = get_object_or_404(Model, pk=id)
    else:
        instance = Model()
    form = ModelForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=instance)

    if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save()
        return redirect(instance)

    return TemplateResponse(request, 'edit.html', {'form': form, })
```